# PHP program will run and echo out nothing

Tags: php

I made a script that reads data from a .xls file and converts it into a .csv, then I have a script that takes the .csv and puts it in an array, and then I have a script with a foreach loop and at the end should echo out the end variable, but it echos out nothing, just a blank page. The file writes okay, and that's for sure, but I don't know if the script read the csv, because if I put an echo after it reads, it just returns blank.

Here my code:

```
    <?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '300M');
$username = 'test';

function convert($in) {

        require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
    $excel = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $excel->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $excel->read($in);
    $x=1;
    $sep = ",";
    ob_start();
    while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']) {
     $y=1;
     $row="";
     while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) {
         $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y]) ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] : '';
         $row.=($row=="")?"\"".$cell."\"":"".$sep."\"".$cell."\"";
         $y++;
     } 
     echo $row."\n"; 
     $x++;
    }

   return ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

}

$csv = convert('usage.xls');

$file = $username . '.csv';
$fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("Can't open the file");
$stringData = $csv;
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

  $maxlinelength = 1000;
$fh = fopen($file);
$firstline = fgetcsv($fh, $maxlinelength);
$cols = count($firstline);

$row = 0;
$inventory = array();
while (($nextline = fgetcsv($fh, $maxlinelength)) !== FALSE )
{
for ( $i = 0; $i < $cols; ++$i )
{
$inventory[$firstline[$i]][$row] = $nextline[$i];
}
++$row;
}
fclose($fh);


$arr = $inventory['Category'];

$texts = 0;
$num2 = 0;
foreach($inventory['Category'] as $key => $value) {
$val = $value;
if (is_object($value)) { echo 'true'; }
        if ($value == 'Messages ') { 
     $texts++; 
     }

}
echo 'You have used ' . $texts . ' text messages';

?>
```

Comment: Try indenting your code so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Once you return. you cannot do anything else in the function:

```
 return ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();//THIS NEVER HAPPENS
```

Therefore the `ob` what never flushed and won't have any output.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of repetitive useless operations there. Why not simply build an array with the data you're pulling out of the Excel file? You can then write out that array with `fputcsv()`, instead of building the CSV string yourself.

You then write the csv out to a file, then read the file back in and process it back into an array. Which begs the question... why? You've already got the raw individual bits of data at the moment you read from the excel file, so why all the fancy-ish giftwrapping only to tear it all apart again?